# Ember.js RESTAdapter attributes types

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

RESTAdapter has built in attribute types of `string`, `number`, `boolean`, and `date`. There are relations to link another models to represent some complex data.

To represent `array` I need to use transformation or change API from something like this:

```
["ember.js", "angular.js", "embergular.js"]
```

to:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "ember.js"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "angular.js"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "embergular.js"
    }
]
```

Which is a little bit overkill... **Why there is no built in types like `array` and `object`?**

Answer (score 3):

IMO the main reason why there aren't such attribute type like array or object is mainly per design.

> To represent array I need to use transformation or change API from something like this:

but to represent an `array` without the needs of building a relation with models you could define a custom transform (what you already mentioned) which don't *touches* your data. For example to use an array as a model attribute you could do something like this:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('rawData', {
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return serialized;
  },  
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
  }   
});
```

Then define it in your model like this:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  myArray: DS.attr('rawData')
});
```

This way the attribute `myArray` will be just what your backend returned, an array or object etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate more why there aren't attributes `array` and `object`? Another thing is when I'm using `rawData` I can display stuff, but after edit and store commit they won't send in the PUT, I see only built in attributes and related models being send.

Comment: OK, I ended up rewriting API. It's much better approach overall. BTW `rawData` example works fine only when displaying stuff, but changes are not included in PUT request.